# My laptop is sending and receiving packets via LAN, but cannot connect to DNS or any other site

Tags: networking, windows-10

My DELL laptop is running Windows 10 Enterprise build 1903. This doesn't have any organisation policy enforced, except the one that forces Windows Update to be ran manually to update.

This is a work network using a Mikrotik at 192.168.1.1, and IPs are manually assigned. My laptop is connected to the network through LAN cable, but won't connect to the internet. The status window shows it keeps sending and receiving packets - a lot, just like normal connection. It cannot ping 8.8.8.8, however.

The Mikrotik can ping to my device just fine and it shows active connection. I can connect via wifi without problem. Other devices on my network connect just fine. Other devices can use my IP just fine. Using different IP also does not work.

Here's what I've done:

1. Doing netsh reset catalog and other netsh commands
2. Doing a network reset
3. Disabling firewall
4. Checking for interfering software

Tried googling my problem, but advices don't seem to work. **What is the problem?**

Comment: Can the Mikrotik ping 8.8.8.8? Do you have any VPN software installed (especially the kind that comes with a "kill switch")? Have you checked the outbound rules in Windows Firewall (`wf.msc`)?

Comment: @grawity yes the mikrotik can ping 8.8.8.8. Every other devices connected by LAN and wifi are working just fine. I don't have any VPN software installed. I don't understand the outbound rules in Windows Firewall, but I haven't touched them. I've also tried to turn the firewall off on domain, private, and public network.

Comment: The ping also doesn't go through even when the firewall is disabled.

Comment: Can you check `route -4 print` from Cmd, or even `Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8` via PowerShell, to see if there's a wrong static route matching it?

Comment: @grawity FindNetRoute http://prntscr.com/of61sh Route from cmd http://prntscr.com/of62ea both when using the LAN

Comment: That looks fairly normal. Do you have the same problem with e.g. 8.8.4.4 or other similar addresses?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96201/discussion-between-vylix-and-grawity).